# Update multiple records in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am attempting to update multiple records in my DB, I have the below code, which I am using to update 1 item.
How do I update multiple?

```
abcProduct productUpdate = dc.abcProducts.Single(p => p.feedSubmitId == submissionId);
productUpdate.prodPublished = '1';
```

Comment: With using a `forach` or any other looping construct?

Comment: Only way to do it in linq2sql is by iterating over the items. If you want set based update you need to use SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
dc.abcProducts.Where(p => p.feedSubmitId == submissionId).ToList().ForEach(x=>x.prodPublished = '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var products = dc.abcProducts.Where(p => p.feedSubmitId == submissionId);
foreach(var product in products)
{
  product.prodPublished = '1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a stored procedure in your database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SetProdPublished
    @submissionId int
    @prodPublished int
AS
    UPDATE AbcProducts SET prodPublished = @prodPublished
    WHERE feedSubmitId = @submissionId
```

Then you drag that stored procedure into your DBML. You can then call that stored procedure.

```
dataContext.SetProdPublished(someSubmissionId, 1);
```

If you are updating more than a few rows, this will be faster than updating them in a loop in code, and much faster if you're updating a lot of rows.